# Using privat var from constructor in new method in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I have written a constuctor

```
function Human() { 
var legs = 2;
var iq = 100; 
}
```

Then I create an instance of the object

```
var Man = new Human();
```

And want to add a new method

```
Man.getIQ = function() {
return iq - 10;
}
```

But I'm told that IQ is undefined. Even if I use this.iq. 
Why isn't a var inside the scope of an object available for new methods?

Comment: You're attempting to extend Woman, but you need to extend the prototype of Human.

Comment: Sorry, if I offended you guys. But beginners need to learn as well. Didn't know that you hade to experienced to ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `legs` and `iq` are simulating a "private" member to the `Human` class because they are visible only in that closure (only in the Human function).
If you want to access them from outside that scope, you need to *make them public* by binding them to the `this` keyword (`this.iq=100;`) or by implementing **getters** and **setters** for each of your *private* member :

```
function Human() { 
    var legs = 2;
    this.getLegs = function(){
        return legs;
    };
}
```

Anyway, these are represent just the very tip of the iceberg; I explained them so that you can understand why what you were trying to do failed.
If I understand correctly what you were trying to do, the right way to write your ideea oop in js would be something like this :

```
function Human(){}
Human.prototype = {
    legs : 2,
    iq : 100
};  

function Woman(){}
Woman.prototype = new Human;
Woman.prototype.getIq = function(){
    return this.eq - 10;
};

var womanInstance = new Woman();
// needless to say that this line is both wrong and misogynistic
alert('a woman has an iq of ' + womanInstance.getIq());
```

Sorry if I got carried away, but there are lots of articles & blogs about javascript oop (such as [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)) that I recommend you read before/while getting stuck with these kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks @gion_13 That helps a lot. My problem was that I wanted to keep the properties privat so they couldn't be changed. And I thought that a new instance of the class would inherent all variables, methodes, and properties. So that I could make a spesific getter for a privat variable from the original constructor. So if I understand you correctly, I should make a getter for the privat var and use the getter in the instance to mainpulate the private value. for just that instance.

Comment: +1 for the iq method, simple, elegant and downright hilarious